# Minimum of two functions

Tags: geogebra

In GeoGebra, is there a way to define a function of two variables which is the pointwise minimum of two functions.

Like `h(x, y):= min(x² + y², x + y)`.

(The GeoGebra `Min` command does something different.)

---

I could work around by means of the `abs` function, whichis available, using `min(a, b) = (a + b - |a - b|) / 2`, but this is not very convenient (actually I need to take the minimum of more than two functions).

Comment: Hmm, I wonder whether the Extremum Command could help somehow..

Comment: @gsamaras No, I am not after the extrema. Pointwise minima between the two functions.

Comment: I was trying something like `Min( Min(x² + y², 0, 1), Min(x + y, 2, 3) )`, but that didn't work out...I read about custom tools, which might be helpful in this case..

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [Conditional Function](https://wiki.geogebra.org/en/If_Command#Conditional_Functions) to create a piecewise function that is equal to f(x) if f(x) < g(x) and g(x) otherwise. The definition of this is:

```
If(f(x) < g(x), f, g)
```

Here's [an example of this in action](https://ggbm.at/ZQwVsXDe).

Comment: Thanks, that's cleaner than my approach with the absolute value. But still inconvenient to take the minimum of several functions, because f and g need to appear twice in the expression, which makes it grow fat very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

One option:  Plot a point A on the x-axis. Compute F=min({f(x(A)),g(x(A)),h(x(A))}).  Plot B=(x(A),F). Create Locus(B,A).

Answer (score 0):

If you want the minimum of two functions f(x) and g(x) then you can define (f(x) + g(x) - abs(f(x) - g(x)))/2